# How can I make an live limit count for entry widget

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I have to make an live limit counter for my password entry field. I need a live limit counter which counts the number of text entered.

I used button to find out text count of the entry field, but I want it live.

My code

```
from tkinter import *

Root=Tk()
Entry1=Entry(Root)
length=len(Entry1.get())
Labellen=Label(Root,text= 
(length,"/10"),bg="black",fg="green")

def check():
    if len(Entry1.get())>10:
        length=len(Entry1.get())
        Labellen.configure(text=("you have reached maximum limit ", length , " /10"),fg="red")    
    else:
        length=len(Entry1.get())
        Labellen.config(text=(length,"/10"))

Entry1.configure(font=('MS Serif',10),bg="light 
blue",relief="groove",bd=15,
insertbackground="red",insertborderwidth=15)
Entry1.pack()

Labellen.pack()

Btn=Button(Root,text="check limit",command=check)
Btn.pack()

Root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the `validatecommand` parameter of tkinter `Entry`. For more details, have a look at the [docs](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/entry-validation.html).

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

def check(why):
    ctr.set(len(why))
    return True

count = root.register(check)
entry = tk.Entry(root, validate="key", validatecommand=(count, '%P'))
entry.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=5)
entry.focus_set()

ctr = tk.StringVar()
ctr.set(0)
tk.Label(root, text='Counter: ').grid()
counter = tk.Label(root, textvariable=ctr, bg='white')
counter.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

[image]